# Place a BitmapIcon in an Ellipse Element in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app, I wish to place a Bitmap Icon inside an Ellipse element. Is there any way to achieve this using the Fill property of the Ellipse, or any other way which allows me to achieve this?

I wish to use Bitmap Icon only because I need to change the colour of the icon using the Foreground property. Is there any way I can create an ImageBrush using a BitmapIcon because this would allow me to fill the Ellipse with an ImageBrush and would help me achieve the UI descibed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ellipse` is a `Shape` object, hence cannot have content or children. But if you want to place your `BitmapIcon` inside an elliptic `Control`, then I think you should use the [`Border`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border) Control.

The `Border` control has `CornerRadius` property. Using that, you can turn it's shape into an elliptic one, or even a circle :

[image]

The output above was achieved with this code:

```
<Border
    Width="200"
    Height="200"
    CornerRadius="100"
    BorderBrush="White"
    BorderThickness="1">

    <BitmapIcon 
        UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"
        Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>

</Border>
```

Does that satisfy your need?

Comment: Yes, initially I had done this only to suit my purpose. But giving corner radius to a Rectangular Border somehow does not lead to a perfect circle. What happened with me was- I had to place the image right in the center of the Circle. But whenever you change the screen resolution from 100% to 150% or any other value, the image did not remain in the center of the circle anymore and got displaced by a few pixels giving a very bad User Experience becuase the image seemed to get displaced.

Comment: Can you add your code as well as a snapshot of the displaced bitmap icon in your question?